# Logging touches' coordinates on ViewController

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I have this newly created Empty project using XCode5. Added a storyboard with one blank `View Controller`. Created a custom view controller class.

Here's the question. How could I log or display the touches on this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Comment: I've added the four methods related to `touches` in the custom view controller class. For each method logged the touches via `touches.allObjects` but it won't display on the console. Is there something I missed?

Comment: It worked. Just forget to comment-out or remove the default codes on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the `AppDelegate` class.